# S.M.A.R.T Failure predicted in harddisk

Tags: hard-drive, smart

Laptop Vaio VPCEB14EN, Segate 320gb HDD, Win7 basic

I am receiving smart failure error from about 8 months. But nothing serious has happened till now. Although I have backed up important data, do u think that I should replace my hdd?

Comment: Just keep backing it up... So you will be ready when it fails. ;)  But if you don't want to back it up every day or so, then maybe you should look into replacing it. PS What is the SMART error?

Comment: SMART:Self-Monitoring, Analysis and Reporting Technology

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I do!

Of course, it may depend on the error, but if it signs as 'dangerous' or 'serious' or similar, time to change.

Although if it were my money, I'd probably consider at intermediate issues.

Now, your issue states Failure, and each SMART tool can report slightly differently. If this was a one off, I'd probably ignore it, if often then I'd replace the hard drive.

Either way, keep  backing up!

Comment: Time to replace before it fails